# Error while accessing a ServicePOJO in JBOSS 5.0.1

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I have a Webapplication with EJBs and ServicePOJOs. When i try to access one of those POJOS, i get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sonydadc.MyAPP.pa.server.PA_Bean.getServername(PA_Bean.java:539)
 at org.apache.jsp.templates.start_jsp._jspService(start_jsp.java:104)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
 at org.apache.jsp.login.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:101)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:444)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:310)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.forwardToLoginPage(FormAuthenticator.java:316)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:244)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

My System: Jboss 5.0.1
           EJB 3.0
           MyFaces 1.1

Can anybody provide some information?

**Update:** here comes the code: This is how i inject the POJO Object

```
@EJB(mappedName = "service/ServPOJOBean") 
@IgnoreDependency 
private ServPOJOBean mb;
```

And this is the line which causes the nullpointerexception:

```
mb.getValue("servername");
```

Strange thing is: it works when i look up the ServicePOJO like this:

```
MBeanServer server = MBeanServerLocator.locate(); 
ServPOJOBean mb = (ServPOJOBean) MBeanProxyExt.
                             create(ServPOJOBean.class, "jboss:service=ServPOJOBean");
```

**Update**

This is how i definedthe ServicePoJO class:

```
@Service(objectName = "jboss:service=ServPOJOBean")
@Management(ServPOJOBean.class)
@Local(ServPOJOBean.class)
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "service/ServPOJOBean")
public class ServPOJOBeanImpl implements ServPOJOBean
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` being thrown from your own code. There's no way we can help you with that without seeing what the code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the injection of your [Service POJOS](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/service/service.html) using the `@EJB` annotation is currently failing, hence the `NullPointerException`. To be honest, I wasn't even aware this was possible - according to the links below it seems to be an "extented" EJB 3 so it should be - but if it is, double check the JNDI name of the remote interface. And maybe show the code of your Service POJO.

#### References

- [Chapter 28. Service POJOs (JBoss extension of EJB3)](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Service_POJOs.html)
- [Chapter 29. Service POJOs (JBoss extension of EJB3) using deployment descriptors](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Service_POJOs_through_deployment_descriptors.html)

Comment: HI,
this way of injecting a ServicePOJO is described in the book "Jboss 5 AS Developement" page 241.

The JNDI name should be right, because i am able to inject a object of that service in another EJB without any problems.

Thanks for the links btw.

I posted some code of the ServiePOJO in my first Posting (see update).

Comment: @binzn Ok, thanks for the ref too, I'll look at this. But still, injection isn't occurring here or you wouldn't get a NPE. What are the differences between both EJBs then (the one that work and the other)? Does it work in the current one if you remove the other?

Comment: hmmm actually, i wrote something wrong. Where the injection is working, is a servlet, not a EJB. Sorry for that.

And is is not working in a backing bean placed a JSF Project.


(Sorry for my english btw. I do not speak english that often)